# Закрывает ли substr незакрытые теги?

Tags: php

Заметил, что `substr` закрывает незакрытые теги. Например, в этом случае:

```
$text = '<p>Text</p>';
$text = substr($text, 0, 5);
```

Переменная `$text` будет содержать в себе `<p>Te</p>`. А в этом:

```
$text = 'O<p>Text</p>';
$text = substr($text, 0, 3);
```

Переменная `$text` будет содержать `O`. То есть, получается, что если есть открытый тег, то он закрывается, а если есть только кусок тега, то он будет удален.

Является ли это документированной особенностью функции?

Comment: Вам показалось. Подробности в студию

Comment: Подробности - в самом вопросе. Проверял на `phpfiddle.org`.

Comment: Наверное браузер сам парсит html и недостающий тег вписывает. Пхп тут не причем

Answer (score 2):

В комментарии писать будет неудобно, сюда - неправильно, но все таки:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Text</p>';
$text = substr($text, 0, 5);
var_dump($text);
```

Результат: `string(5) "<p>Te"`

Говорю же - показалось

PS. PHP 5.4.45, PHP 5.2.17, PHP 4.3.11